# Tailwind: big image centered, small icon top-right corner

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I would like to achieve something like this in Tailwind css
[image]

A big image centered in the div and a small icon at its top-right corner

Update 1:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/2Q9owJd8id

I appreciate any suggetion

thank you

Comment: what have you tried so far? please add your starter code

Comment: Create a container with `flex`. Here's an example: https://play.tailwindcss.com/oncceg7xvm

Comment: @doğukan I added code